# How to import GcmListenerService in android studio?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am creating android application 'GoogleCloudMessaging'. I Have found many that 'GcmListenerService' is being used and the old method 'GCMIntentService' is now deprecated.
I have already install the Google Play service and add it into the dependency.
But when i try to import

```
 import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;
```

it gives error "cannot resolve symbol."
How can I import the Class?
I refer https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging and
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmListenerService.html#GcmListenerService()
and follow the things but still unable to solve the problem.

Comment: what version of google play services are you using, post your gradle

Comment: also there is an small tutorial on how to set it up here https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have already added Google Play Services to your dependencies, the issue might be its version.

Try to update the line(in your build.gradle) to:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

Then sync your project.

Comment: GCMListenerService was added in 7.5.0 previous versions will not have it.

Comment: **compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'**  this version i have added. I have download it from the **SDK->extras->google play services**.

Answer (score 2):

You must include

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
```

in your build.gradle file.